# Getting a 400 bad request on deploying to azure using local Git

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am following the instructions here to deploy from my local Git to my Azure web service app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git

I have completed every thing else; but while actually deploying my branch to the web-app by doing this:

```
git push https://myusername:mypassword@myapp-test.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/myapp.git deploybranch
```

I get this response:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://myusername:mypassword@myapp-test.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/myapp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

I have double checked and changed my deployment credentials under the deployment credential settings several times and tried it with and without the explicit setting of :433 port.

Everything else seems to be fine, but I get no other response other than 400 bad request. No further details either. Why is it that this deployment is not going through?

EDIT: So, it looks like I was trying to set up a different source control for a deployment slot within a web application, and it did not work for that. After spooling up a simple small web-app service to test it on fresh grounds, it seems to be okay. But the question still remains: why the 400? Shouldn't a deployment slot be considered as a separate app, considering that you can set up different deployment strategies for each?

Comment: Can you repro that on a test site and share its name?